# Inserting binary tree node

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm trying to insert a node to my tree.

```
   public void addNode(BinaryTree playerOrTeamLeaf) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new BinaryTree(playerOrTeamLeaf);
                return;
            } else if (left != null) {
                left.addNode(playerOrTeamLeaf);
            }

            if (right == null) {
                right = new BinaryTree(playerOrTeamLeaf);
                return;
            } else if (right != null) {
                right.addNode(playerOrTeamLeaf);
                return;
            }
        }
```

As you can tell this is a troubled tree. this is what the tree currently looks like.

```
       a
     b   
   d   
 e
```

As you can tell the left if condition runs first,this is what causes the problem.

I am aiming for a nice equal tree. I know what the problem is say we have a tree of size 4 IE.

```
    A
  B   
C
```

To my logic code runs along the lines of this pseudo code (this is an insert of the 5th leaf) it start at 'A' we are inserting 'D:

```
 if left is null then left is equal to a new Node then return; | left = 'B'
 else if left is not null
 go to left object add method and pass in 'E';
     if left is null then left is equal to a new Node then return; | left = 'C'      else if left is not null
     go to left object add method and pass in 'E';
                   if left is null then left is equal to a new Node then | //seee below
```

So this leaves my tree looking like this.

```
      A
    B   
  D
E
```

I know that it is doing this because of the first if statement but the logic of how to get around this has left me bamboozled. I have tried to swap around the left and right statements but that just flips the side in which the tree grows.

I am aware that this is a linked list essentially but I'm not sure how I can get around doing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you merely trying to keep the tree even, or are you sorting the tree based on a "key"?

Comment: What the desired tree looks like? I don't know what kind of tree you trying to build. Your current logic seem will only add node to the left side of the tree.

Comment: basically an equal tree 8/16/32 nodes at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

The very general idea is something like:

```
BinaryTree insert(Binary tree, int value) {
    if (tree == null) {
        return new BinaryTree(value);
    }
    if (value < tree.value) {
        tree.left = insert(tree.left, value);
    } else if (value > tree.value) {
        tree.right = insert(tree.right, value);
    }
    return tree;
}

BinaryTree tree = null;
tree = insert(tree, 19);
tree = insert(tree, 7);
tree = insert(tree, 23)
tree = insert(tree, 11);

           19
           /\
          7  23
           \
            11

         7 11 19 23
```

This ensures inserting at one place.